# ReCaptcha v3 slow response since 2 weeks

Tags: curl, recaptcha, file-get-contents

I have 2 servers, one for testing (small pc) and a big server, both with ubuntu. Both have cloned configs, settings and files using rsync. The problem is, that since 2 weeks, the big server is getting slowdown by google response times from reCaptcha v3. On the testing machine, the response time from curl post is 0.3 seconds (very acceptable times) but on the server, I get 10 seconds average. Both PC share the SAME ISP and router, so its not a speed issue or firewall (already checked, and uses the same config on both).

I use this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch,
                  [
                      CURLOPT_URL            => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
                      CURLOPT_POST           => TRUE,
                      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => [
                          'secret'   => $secretKey,
                          'response' => $captchaToken,
                          'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                      ],
                      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                  ]);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

also tried this code, with same results:

```
        $output =
        file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" .
                          $secretKey .
                          "&response=" .
                          $captchaToken);
```

EDIT: more details for the response from google to the "slow server". The other response is equal except for the google IP:

```
Main (Slow) server : 172.217.172.36
Test Server: 172.217.162.4
```

and the debug results:

```
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 172.217.162.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.google.com (172.217.162.4) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=www.google.com
*  start date: Mar 24 06:49:44 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 16 06:49:44 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.google.com" matched cert's                     "www.google.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=GTS CA 1O1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /recaptcha/api/siteverify HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 810
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------        -3e838894f384bb29

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 16:02:13 GMT
< Expires: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 16:02:13 GMT
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Server: GSE
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443";     ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-    Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443";     ma=2592000
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact
```

[EDITS]

it seems that the problem was googles and cloudfire DNS.. both cannot be accessed via my ISP since 2 weeks (don't know why), I change server DNS to OpenDNS, and now it work fast again... TEMPORARY.

Comment: add ```$curl_stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$curl_stderrh));$output = curl_exec($ch);/*https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268*/rewind($curl_stderrh);$curl_stderr=stream_get_contents($curl_stderrh);fclose($curl_stderrh);var_dump($curl_stderr);``` , what do you get?

Comment: @hanshenrik I added the results to the OP

Comment: add the log both from the fast response, and from the slow response, and specify which is which. i have no idea if that log is from the fast response, or the slow response, and i want to see both.

Comment: @hanshenrik both are exaclty the same except that SLOW server version shows this IP *   Trying 172.217.172.36...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.google.com (172.217.172.36) port 443 (#0)

Comment: and what OS are the servers running on? anyway, ping both ips (`172.217.162.4` and `172.217.172.36`) from both servers, are the ping times significantly different between the 2?

Comment: also run `var_dump(curl_version());` , what do you get on both servers?  (for example, does the fast server roll OpenSSL and the slow server roll GnuTLS?)

Comment: @hanshenrik it seems that DNS is involved... if I change it it get some speed temporary. I use ubuntu 18.04 on all PCs

Comment: maybe your slow server just use a slow DNS by default? try adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to /etc/resolv.conf , 8.8.8.8 is a very fast public DNS server owned&operated by Google ( https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using )

Comment: @hanshenrik I'm using 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, and OpendDNS.